# NAT rule doesn't work

Tags: networking, routing, nat

I have the following situation on my host:

```
       vethZ
      10.0.0.3
         o  
         |       -----------------             
         --------|--o         o--|----o         o--- internet
                 | vethX   vethY | vethW       eth0
                 |               |           192.168.0.9
                 |   namespace   |
                 -----------------
```

The routing configuration has been made using policy based routing.
According to that, a packet sent from the host to the Internet (e.g., using ping) enters into my network through vethZ, then goes in the namespace. From here, it is forwarded to vethW, then to eth0 and reaches the Internet.

I want to configure a NAT rule that masquerades all the internal IP address using the eth0 IP (192.168.0.9).
I have then added the rule using iptables

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

However, my packets reaches `eth0` without being masqueraded by the rule above.

Does someone know the reason?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If you list out the iptables rules, is the masquerade rule there?

Comment: Yes, I can see the rule

Comment: Have you tried any other NAT rules, just to see if they take effect?

Comment: I have tried the rule `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to 192.168.0.9` but it doesn't work. I have also tried to put veth5 into a namespace and the rule works, but I don't want my vethZ into a namespace and I cannot understand why the rule doesn't take effect if vethZ is not into a namespace.